# Why is my program not printing right values to the summary report?

Tags: python

I am working on this program for class and I am nearly done but on line 96 down, I try to make a summary report that summarizes different employee information but I can't get it to actually do it. The program just sets all of the summary report values to zero. No traceback errors.
Here is the code:

```
from Data import Employee
import queue
import csv

#Initialize Queues
input_queue = queue.Queue()
payStubs_queue = queue.Queue()

fields = ['ID', 'Name', 'Title', 'Hours Worked', 'Hourly Wage', 'Federal Tax Rate']

rows = [['1234', 'Franklin', 'Engineer', '2', '9.0', '.20'],
        ['5467', 'Raberto', 'Developer', '2', '9.1', '.20'],
        ['2345', 'Caity', 'FrontEnd', '2', '9.3', '.20'],
        ['1235', 'Patrick', 'FrontEnd', '1', '9.5', '.20'],
        ['3465', 'Prateek', 'Engineer', '3', '7.8', '.20'],
        ['4567', 'Alberto', 'Engineer', '2', '9.1', '.20'],
        ['5678', 'Orin', 'Engineer', '2', '9.0', '.20'],
        ['1678', 'Eric', 'Developer', '2', '9.1', '.20'],
        ['7565', 'Jose', 'FrontEnd', '2', '9.3', '.20'],
        ['5677', 'Alberto', 'FrontEnd', '1', '9.5', '.20'],
        ['7325', 'Alfred', 'Engineer', '3', '7.8', '.20'],
        ['9043', 'Albert', 'Engineer', '2', '9.1', '.20'],
        ['3065', 'Sarah', 'FrontEnd', '1', '9.5', '.20'],
        ['9042', 'John', 'Engineer', '3', '7.8', '.20'],
        ['2346', 'Tyler', 'Engineer', '2', '9.1', '.20']]

filename = "EmployeeInfo.csv"


'''Writing to the File.'''
try:
    with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        csv_writer.writerow(fields)
        csv_writer.writerows(rows)
except IOError:
    print("This file does not exist.")
except Exception as err:
    print(f"Unexpected error opening {filename} is",repr(err))
except OSError:
    print(f"OS error occurred trying to open {filename}")


'''Reading the File.'''
try:
    '''with open('EmployeeInfo.csv') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        for line in csv_file:
            emp_id, first_name, job_title, hours_worked, hourly_wage, federal_tax_rate = (field.strip() for field in line.split(","))'''
    with open('EmployeeInfo.csv') as csv_file:
        cvsRead = csv.reader(csv_file)
        
        next(csv_file, None)
        for line in cvsRead:
            emp_id, first_name, job_title, hours_worked, hourly_wage, federal_tax_rate = (field.strip() for field in line)
            employee = Employee(emp_id, first_name, job_title, float(hours_worked), float(hourly_wage), float(federal_tax_rate))
            input_queue.put(employee)
except IOError:
    print("This file does not exist.")
except Exception as err:
    print(f"Unexpected error opening {filename} is",repr(err))
except OSError:
    print(f"OS error occurred trying to open {filename}")


'''Process data from the input queue and enqueue pay stubs into the payStubs queue.'''
while not input_queue.empty():
    employee = input_queue.get()
    gross_pay = employee.calculate_gross_pay()
    federal_tax = employee.calculate_federal_tax()
    
    state_tax = 0.1 * gross_pay
    social_security_tax = 0.05 * gross_pay
    medicare_tax = 0.02 * gross_pay
    
    net_pay = gross_pay - (federal_tax + state_tax + social_security_tax + medicare_tax)
    
    pay_stub = (employee.emp_id, f'{employee.first_name}', gross_pay, federal_tax, state_tax, social_security_tax, medicare_tax, net_pay)
    payStubs_queue.put(pay_stub)


'''Saves pay stub into text file.'''
try:
    with open('Covington.txt', 'w') as output_file:
        while not payStubs_queue.empty():
            pay_stub = payStubs_queue.get()
            output_file.write(','.join(map(str, pay_stub)) + '\n')
except IOError:
    print("This file does not exist.")
except Exception as err:
    print(f"Unexpected error opening {filename} is",repr(err))
except OSError:
    print(f"OS error occurred trying to open {filename}")


'''Generates a summary report.'''
total_gross_pay = 0
total_federal_tax = 0
total_state_tax = 0
total_social_security_tax = 0
total_medicare_tax = 0

try:
    with open('summary.txt', 'w') as summary_file:
        while not payStubs_queue.empty():
            pay_stub = payStubs_queue.get()
            total_gross_pay += pay_stub[2]
            total_federal_tax += pay_stub[3]
            total_state_tax += pay_stub[4]
            total_social_security_tax += pay_stub[5]
            total_medicare_tax += pay_stub[6]
            
            summary_file.write(f'Employee ID: {pay_stub[0]}, Employee Name: {pay_stub[1]}, Net Pay: {pay_stub[7]}\n')
except IOError:
    print("This file does not exist.")
except Exception as err:
    print(f"Unexpected error opening {filename} is",repr(err))
except OSError:
    print(f"OS error occurred trying to open {filename}")

try:
    with open('summary.txt', 'w') as summary_file:
        summary_file.write(f'Total Gross Pay for All Employees: {total_gross_pay}\n')
        summary_file.write(f'Total Federal Taxes Withheld for All Employees: {total_federal_tax}\n')
        summary_file.write(f'Total State Taxes Withheld for All Employees: {total_state_tax}\n')
        summary_file.write(f'Total Social Security Withheld for All Employees: {total_social_security_tax}\n')
        summary_file.write(f'Total Medicare Amount Withheld for All Employees: {total_medicare_tax}\n')
except IOError:
    print("This file does not exist.")
except Exception as err:
    print(f"Unexpected error opening {filename} is",repr(err))
except OSError:
    print(f"OS error occurred trying to open {filename}")

#Prints summary to the screen
print(f'Total Gross Pay for All Employees: {total_gross_pay}\n')
print(f'Total Federal Taxes Withheld for All Employees: {total_federal_tax}\n')
print(f'Total State Taxes Withheld for All Employees: {total_state_tax}\n')
print(f'Total Social Security Withheld for All Employees: {total_social_security_tax}\n')
print(f'Total Medicare Amount Withheld for All Employees: {total_medicare_tax}\n')
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Side note: except blocks are tried sequentially, so having `except Exception:` before `except OSError:` makes it impossible for the `except OSError:` block to be reached. `OSErrors`s are `Exception`s, so they'll be handled in the `except Exception` block.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I read that article it was very good! I definitely need to get better at debugging. Right now my biggest problem with python, and specifically this assignment, is that my knowledge base of python isn't very large. Which makes it hard for me sometimes to deug. Thank you for the advice though I am going to start learning about assertions!

Answer (score 0):

In the `with open('Covington.txt', 'w') as output_file:` section, you read all "pay stubs" out of `payStubs_queue`, so when you try to do it again in the `with open('summary.txt', 'w') as summary_file:` section, the queue will be empty and there will be no values added to the `total_*` variables that are used for the summary report.

Comment: Thank you! I just started learning about queues and don't understand a lot of it. I will try to get better at debugging and get me a rubber duck!